# About limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac {f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}
=0$. But if we assume $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ along the curve $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$, then limit becomes equal to 1. How to get rid of this kind of things?

Comment: The curve $f=g$ cannot have $(0,0)$ as a limit point.

Comment: How do you know $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ describes a curve in the first place?

Comment: Actually I find a problem here. Please elaborate it!